# I installed nginx server on mac os x. Now i try to restart it and get below error.

Tags: macos, nginx

I tried to install nginx serve on mac os x by following below link, when i try to restart server gives me below error.

[How to install Nginx webserver on Mac OS X](https://www.hrupin.com/2017/11/how-to-install-nginx-webserver-on-mac-os-x)

```
sudo nginx -s stop

nginx: [error] invalid PID number "   " in "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nginx: [error] invalid PID number "   " in "/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid"` message most likely means that nginx is not started.

Try to start it first by just typing `nginx`.

To make sure nginx has started successfully, execute `ps -ax | grep nginx`. Output on my machine:

```
MacBook-Pro-Aleksej:~ alexey$ nginx
MacBook-Pro-Aleksej:~ alexey$ ps -ax | grep nginx
69982 ??         0:00.00 nginx: master process nginx
69984 ??         0:00.00 nginx: worker process
69995 ttys000    0:00.00 grep nginx
```

Comment: `logicPs-MacBook-Air:run shak$ sudo nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (48: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
logicPs-MacBook-Air:run shak$ sudo nginx stop
Password:
nginx: invalid option: "stop"
logicPs-MacBook-Air:run shak$ ps -ax | grep nginx
99801 ttys003    0:00.00 grep nginx` But when hit localhost or 127.0.0.1 , it loads xampp phpmyadmin page. Thanks

Comment: I checked /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid file it is blank file , i.e., is nginx: [error] invalid PID number is returned.

Comment: `Address already in use` message means that you already have some server running on ports 80 and 443. Obviously, it's XAMPP. You need to either shutdown that server or to configure nginx to run on different ports. BTW, command to stop nginx is `nginx -s stop`.

Answer (score 2):

try

> brew services restart nginx

then

> nginx -s reload

Answer (score 0):

First Check nginx service is running or not

```
brew services
```

[image]

*Here nginx is not runing first need run nginx type command bellow terminal*

```
nginx
```

*Note : if you are getting this something like this error
nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.23.2/logs/kartify-direct-error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)*

Then use sudo command

```
sudo nginx
```